# Python number formatting difference

Tags: python, formatting, number-formatting

I am a beginner without much knowledge of number formatting and could not find resources on this topic. Could someone explain what these notations mean or direct me to some resources?

I understand that format #1 means that d is formatted to have two fixed digits, and is padded by zeros on the left.

1. '%02d/%04d/%03d' % (x, y, z)
2. format(x, '100,d'))

Comment: https://www.udacity.com/blog/2020/11/python-string-format-whats-the-difference-between-s-and-d.html or select a similar one

Comment: @PM77-1 couldn't find the format() notation in the link

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings